# Python linesplitting into sections

Tags: python

Hi I am uncertain on how to solve a problem I have that involves linesplitting. I need to read lines that have the following format. Line appearance have been altered with placeholder names for easier reading.

```
/etc/xxx/gainValueX       S32         5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6, 7, 10
```

What I am aiming to do is split parts of the line into three different variables. One for the "/etc/xxx/..." part, one for the "S32" part and one for all the numbers in the line. The problem is that the parts with the numbers are separated with commas while the others merely have a space between them.

Heres how my code looks this far

```
for line in ins:¨
        pieces = line.split()
        addressParam = pieces[0]
        dataType = pieces[1]

        num = line.split(',')

        for numbers in num:
            print(numbers)
```

Here I split the line into sections in the "pieces" variable and then I can atleast easily get the first and second part of the line into addressParam and dataType variable without any difficulty. The problem is as stated with the number part. When doing a testrun and printing the num variable I not only get the numbers but the other parameters aswell. Here's an example of how a run of the script looks like

```
/etc/xxx/gainValueX         S32     -393
 -368
 -174
 -68
 69
 177
 276
 374
```

So to summarize. How do I properly save the numbers into a variable and nothing else after splitting the line the way I've done so far? I hope I've made myself clear and that the problem is easy to understand.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying you would like all the numbers assigned to one variable?

Comment: You are splitting on comma on the whole line `num = line.split(',')`.

Comment: Ye exactly. I want to split the numbers part of the line into one variable. So I get a list of them basicly.

Comment: Ah derp you're right AKS..What would I need to write instead if I only wanted to handle the numbers part?

Comment: Are the numbers separated by comma only or comma + space?

Comment: Ah its both a comma and a space

Comment: You can use `pieces[2:]` to get all the numbers - but you need to loop over it to remove the commas at the end.

Comment: Ah excellent :). Looping through and removing the commas worked fine. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following will give you all the numbers in a list

```
num = [x.replace(',', '') for x in pieces[2:]]
# ['5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '6', '7', '10']
```

What you did earlier was:

```
num  = line.split(',')
# the output of above is
# ['/etc/xxx/gainValueX       S32         5', ' 4', ' 3', ' 2', ' 1', ' 6', ' 7', ' 10']
```

Answer (score 1):

The following script would let you access the various parts:

```
import re

line = "/etc/xxx/gainValueX       S32         5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6, 7, 10"
re_line = re.match("(.*?)\s+(.*?)\s+(.*)", line)

path = re_line.group(1)
part = re_line.group(2)
numbers = [int(x) for x in re_line.group(3).split(",")]

print "Path:", path
print "Part:", part
print "Numbers:", numbers
```

Giving you:

```
Path: /etc/xxx/gainValueX
Part: S32
Numbers: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6, 7, 10]
```

Tested on Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Because you have white space between your numbers you wont simply be able to perform `line.split()`

If your data is consistent structure, you could use the following:

```
nums = "".join(line.split())[2:]
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want it to split into `"/etc/xxx/gainValueX", "S32", "5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6, 7, 10"`? In that case you'd do `line.split(None, 2)`. The idea here is to split the usual way on white space (that's what the `None` means), but only split it into three parts (two split points) and that's what the `2` is for.

If you then want to split the numbers apart you could do a normal `numbers.split(",")` to do that, possibly using `strip` if you want to remove the whitespaces (ie `[x.strip for x in numbers.split(',')]`)

Answer (score 0):

You should use two steps:

1. split line by whitespace, then
2. split the numbers separately, after turning the commas into spaces

Here's an example, based on input above:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

while True:
    try:
        line = raw_input('Input? ')
        parts = line.split(' ',2)
        print "Parts:"
        for x, part in enumerate(parts):
            print "  %d: %s" % (x, part)

        numbers = parts[2].replace(',', ' ').split()
        print "Numbers:"
        for x, num in enumerate(numbers):
            print "  %d: %s" % (x, num)
    except:
        break
```

Here is the sample run:

```
$ ./test.py
Input? foo bar 1, 2,3 , 4,5
Parts:
  0: foo
  1: bar
  2: 1, 2,3 , 4,5
Numbers:
  0: 1
  1: 2
  2: 3
  3: 4
  4: 5
```

Answer (score -2):

Just create the string and then print it. Print ads a linefeed to the end of the string, so why not do this

```
for line in ins:
    pieces = line.split()
    addressParam = pieces[0]
    dataType = pieces[1]

    num = ''.join(pieces[2:]).split(',')
    for number in num:
        print number
```

The num variable now only has the numbers in them.